# PyQt-QtableView Header. How to add top-right small button to hide/show column with checked/unchecked Checkboxes?

Tags: qt, checkbox, pyqt4, qtableview

With PyQt4, I am using a QtableView with more than 10 columns. The user must have the choice of showing/hiding a column.

This is generally done by adding a small button in the top-right of the table's header. The button shows a menu with checked/unchecked Checkboxes allowing to hide/show columns.

This is an example from [Sqlite-Manager Table](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/SQLiteManager.png).
So, I wonder how can I do the same with PyQt's QtableView?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Kitsune Meyoko, it was a great Idea.. ;)

I found another solution pretty much like yours by using QMenu with Checkable QActions instead of a QPushButton: Let's Go:

```
import sys
import string
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Header(QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Header, self).__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.ctxMenu)

        self.setup()

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def printID(self, i):
        print("id")
        if i == False:
            self.hideSection(0)
        else:
            self.showSection(0)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)        
    def printNAME(self, i):
        print("name")
        if i == False:
            self.hideSection(1)
        else:
            self.showSection(1)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)        
    def printUSERNAME(self, i):
        print("username")
        if i == False:
            self.hideSection(2)
        else:
            self.showSection(2)

    def setup(self):

        self.id = QAction("id",self)
        self.id.setCheckable(True)
        self.id.setChecked(True)
        self.connect(self.id, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("printID(bool)"))


        self.name = QAction("name",self)
        self.name.setCheckable(True)
        self.name.setChecked(True)
        self.connect(self.name, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("printNAME(bool)"))


        self.username = QAction("username",self)
        self.username.setCheckable(True)
        self.username.setChecked(True)
        self.connect(self.username, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self, SLOT("printUSERNAME(bool)"))

    def ctxMenu(self, point):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        self.currentSection = self.logicalIndexAt(point)
        menu.addAction(self.id)
        menu.addAction(self.name)
        menu.addAction(self.username)
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(Header(self))
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'name', 'username'])
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.setRowCount(10)
        for i in range(10):
            for j,l in enumerate(string.ascii_letters[:3]):
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(l)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Table()
    t.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Sound good. Ara..... if I hidden all, It will can't right clicked again. It should be handle in `QTableWidget` more than ? Or is it good to handle with button ?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I think the user have no interest to hide all sections. So One can disable hiding sections when just one section remains visible!

Comment: Yes, it should be no interest to hide all sections. But it can possibility to set hide all. If user accident to hidden all and want to show it again, it can't do it back. So, user can think it is 'BUG', isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

In `QTableView` not have kind of button just like "Sqlite-Manager Table". But your can custom widget by using [`QtGui.QPushButton`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpushbutton.html) and work with [`QtGui.QMenu`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenu.html) together to get column from user. And use [`QTableView.hideColumn (self, int column)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html#hideColumn) & [`QTableView.showColumn (self, int column)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html#showColumn) to hide show your column;

Full example;

```
import sys
import random
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomTableViewWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, myQStandardItemModel, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QCustomTableViewWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Layout setup
        self.localQTableView        = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.rightCornerQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        menuQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        menuQHBoxLayout.addStretch(1)
        menuQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.rightCornerQPushButton)
        allQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        allQVBoxLayout.addLayout(menuQHBoxLayout)
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.localQTableView)
        self.setLayout(allQVBoxLayout)
        # Object setup
        self.localQTableView.setModel(myQStandardItemModel)
        self.rightCornerQPushButton.setText('Show column')
        currentQMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
        for column in range(myQStandardItemModel.columnCount()):
            currentQAction = QtGui.QAction('Column %d' % (column + 1), currentQMenu)
            currentQAction.setCheckable(True)
            currentQAction.setChecked(True)
            currentQAction.toggled.connect(partial(self.setColumnVisible, column))
            currentQMenu.addAction(currentQAction)
        self.rightCornerQPushButton.setMenu(currentQMenu)

    def setColumnVisible (self, column, isChecked):
        if isChecked:
            self.localQTableView.showColumn(column)
        else:
            self.localQTableView.hideColumn(column)

    def tableView (self):
        return self.localQTableView

# Simulate data
myQStandardItemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for _ in range(10):
    myQStandardItemModel.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('%d' % random.randint(100, 999)), QtGui.QStandardItem('%d' % random.randint(100, 999)), QtGui.QStandardItem('%d' % random.randint(100, 999))])

# Main application
myQApplication           = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQCustomTableViewWidget = QCustomTableViewWidget(myQStandardItemModel)
myQCustomTableViewWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```